# MatLab: Sorting two row vectors

Tags: matlab

I have two row vectors (i_1,i_2,...,i_n) and (b_1,b_2,...,b_n) where i_1 corresponds to b_1.
I need to consider the case where the i elements are not necessarily in order so must be sorted, how do I do this while also making sure the b elements are rearranged so that they still correspond to the correct i element. I have the following sorting code that I need to use but am unsure how to adapt it to do what I need it to.

```
function [ out ] = myMsort( a )
%MYMSORT returns a sorted version of the input row vector, by merging
% Merge sort: running time O(n log n) with n elements to sort
% But really quite inefficient for small n

n=length(a);
if (n==1)
out=a; return
end
out=myMerge(myMsort(a(1,1:floor(n/2))),myMsort(a(1,floor(n/2)+1:n)));

end
```

Where the function called within this is as follows

```
function [ out ] = myMerge( a,b )
% MYMERGE: takes two sorted row vectors and produces the (sorted) merge
% running time linear in output size 
out=zeros(1,length(a)+length(b)); % Avoid growing array!
j=1;k=1;l=1;
while (j<=length(a))&&(k<=length(b))
if (a(1,j)<b(1,k))
out(1,l)=a(1,j); j=j+1;l=l+1;
else
out(1,l)=b(1,k); k=k+1;l=l+1;
end
end

while (j<=length(a))
out(1,l)=a(1,j); j=j+1;l=l+1;
end
while (k<=length(b))
out(1,l)=b(1,k); k=k+1;l=l+1;
end
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you say "I have the following sorting code that I need to use" I assume you mean you can't use Matlab's `sort` or `sortrows`?

Comment: [sortrows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) or [sort](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) ?

Comment: @aganders3 `sort` function aren't from toolbox. It base on matlab.

Comment: @aganders3 unfortunately not, the codes in my question are what i've been advised to use and to avoid MatLab's 'buit in' sorting programmes

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau I know, I assume this is part of an assignment or something in which they are learning about sorting and thus 
"not allowed" to use the built-in functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the code to accept multiple rows of data, but still just sort all columns based on the values in the first row. This requires only small changes: first, change every instance of `length(a)` or `length(b)` to `size(a,2)` and `size(b,2)`. Then make sure in the merge assignments you transfer all elements from that column by using the `:` indexing operator, instead of `1`.

```
function [ out ] = myMsort( a )
n=size(a,2);
if (n==1)
    out=a;
    return
end

out=myMerge(myMsort(a(:,1:floor(n/2))),myMsort(a(:,floor(n/2)+1:n)));

end

function [ out ] = myMerge( a,b )
    out=zeros(size(a,1),size(a,2)+size(b,2)); % Avoid growing array!

    j=1;k=1;l=1;
    while (j<=size(a,2))&&(k<=size(b,2))
        if (a(1,j)<b(1,k))
            out(:,l)=a(:,j);
            j=j+1;l=l+1;
        else
            out(:,l)=b(:,k);
            k=k+1;l=l+1;
        end
    end

    while (j<=size(a,2))
        out(:,l)=a(:,j);
        j=j+1;l=l+1;
    end
    while (k<=size(b,2))
        out(:,l)=b(:,k);
        k=k+1;l=l+1;
    end
end
```

Now you can run the code like so:

```
n = 100;
i = rand([1 n]);
b = rand([1 n]);
out = myMsort([i;b]);
```

And `out` will be a matrix of two rows: row 1 is the sorted values of `i` and row 2 is the corresponding values from `b`.

Comment: I have tried this but I still get an error with the sorted=myMsort(index;b); and i'm not sure why

Comment: What does the error say? Try using `sorted = myMsort([index;b]);` and note the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Just little modification, here my example :

```
a = [12,4,1,2,8,7];
```

and into myMsort, I change :

```
out=myMerge(myMsort(a(1:floor(n/2))),myMsort(a(floor(n/2)+1:n)));
```

where all line are already sorted.

I don't really understand the part a is two row

**EDIT**

here the full myMsort function :

```
function [ out ] = myMsort( a )
%MYMSORT returns a sorted version of the input row vector, by merging
% Merge sort: running time O(n log n) with n elements to sort
% But really quite inefficient for small n
a = reshape(a,1,size(a,1)*size(a,2));

n=length(a);
if (n==1)
    out=a; return
end

out=myMerge(myMsort(a(1:floor(n/2))),myMsort(a(floor(n/2)+1:n)));

end
```

Note that i'm using reshape to make a single row array. You can do it by yourself with another function. the problem is with the recursion your out need to be 2 row vector but it not when myMerge return.